# Reveal.Member issue in mapping one-to-one mapping with Fluent and Nhibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, one-to-one

I was following Bruno's excellent [article](http://brunoreis.com/tech/fluent-nhibernate-hasone-how-implement-one-to-one-relationship/comment-page-1/#comment-2435)  for one-to-one mapping in fluent Nhibernate. However I ran into a small trouble while mapping the private entities with an error which is not clear. Here are my entities, mapping and error:

**Entities**

```
public class Student
{
    public virtual String Studentid { get; set; }       
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }             
}
 public class Address
{
    private String StudentId { get; set; }
    private Student Student { get; set; }

    public Address(Student student)
    { Student = student; }
}
```

**Mapping :**

```
public StudentMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Studentid).GeneratedBy.Assigned();          
        HasOne(x => x.Address).Cascade.All();
    }

public AddressMap()
    { 
        Id(x=> Reveal.Member<Address>("StudentId"))
                    .GeneratedBy.Foreign("Student");

        HasOne( x=> Reveal.Member<Address,Student>("Student"))                             
                .Constrained()
                .ForeignKey();

    }
```

Now when I am trying to run it it's giving error as:

> Could not determine type for: System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[[System.Func`2[[CastleTest.Domain.Address, CastleTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(Member)

Why is this error happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
HasOne(x => Reveal.Member<Address,Student>("Student"))
```

to

```
HasOne(Reveal.Member<Address,Student>("Student"))
```

because FNH thinks `x => Reveal.Member` is `x => x.Member`

the call `Reveal.Member<Address,Student>("Student")` returns something like `adress => adress.Student`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. can you please tell whats the diffrence between the two ??? although it worked alright ... jus need to know why did it gave error . cause i am a very novice in fluent nhibernate

Comment: `x => x.Student` is a lambda expression which is parsed by FNH to get the propertyname, but if the property is not public you cant access it in a lambda so there is `Reveal` which constructs the lambda. so `x=> Reveal.Member` will be parsed to get the Propertyname `Member`